# Waiting for resources in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a Javascript library.  It currently uses a synchronous XMLHttmpRequest to get information from the server, caches the result, and has functions which create objects based on input to the function and the cached data.  These functions could conceivably cause another synchronous request, but this is extremely rare after the initial page load.

"Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detremental effects to the end user's experience."

All the examples I've found say "Use a callback when the resource is loaded."  But the functions which could trigger the load are used in a large number of places, the majority of which cannot be readily modified to say "Call this and continue when you have a value."  Altering that particular behavior would be a substantial architecture change I cannot afford at this time.

What I really want is "block until the XMLHttpRequest is done or errored," a thing I can no longer do in the main UI.  **I feel like there should be some way to use callbacks within my library to accomplish this, without changing the library interface, but I can't figure one out.**

I've couched the question in general terms, now I'll give some specifics.  The library generates and manipulates date objects for time systems other than the current browser's.

```
var foo = new dateLibrary.date(utime, "Etc/UTC");
```

If it has not had a call using that time system, it does a load and parse of the time system prior to creating and returning the date object.  It is then used on a d3 and SVG using page to create nice-looking, rich displays.  Turning it into something of the form

```
dateLibrary.date(utime, "Etc/UTC", callbackUsingResult(date));
```

will require reaching into the guts of d3 or abandoning its ability to use generate time axis information.

Comment: By the way, the vast majority of the time any loading which is done hits the browser cache.  Even when it hasn't, the time taken to get the XMLHttpRequest has so far not been an issue.

Comment: For now, I am precomputing the relevant time systems and loading them early, with a callback to actually start the rest of the page's javascript.  So I've found a way to use callbacks, it'll just be harder to maintain.
If anyone finds a way to do it without changing the library interface and without precomputing the relevant time systems please add an answer.